# elc image picker issues in ipod with ios 4

Tags: iphone, ios4

i am using elc image picker controller in my application and it is working fine in iphone when i tried to run the app ipod( with ios 4.0 ) the albums view controller shows the duplicate of the albums

![enter image description here][1]

i just added the screen shot of the duplicate of images

can any one please tell me why this is happening only in ipod (with ios 4.0) with out camera only.

if i log the number of asserts the count displays one extra number then the exact count of asserts in ipod touch .